# Error C2664 when declaring an array of shared_ptr with a custom object

Tags: c++, arrays, shared-ptr

I keep getting an error when using:

```
std::shared_ptr<ModelType> out(new shared_ptr<ModelType>[m_MAX]);
```

Isn't it the correct way to instantiate an array of shared_ptr?
The error is the following:

error C2664: 'void std::_Ptr_base<_Ty>::_Reset0(_Ty *,std::_Ref_count_base *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr *' to 'ModelType *'

thanks in advance

Comment: Use `std::shared_ptr<ModelType> = std::make_shared<ModelType>();` instead. I am not sure if you can create a shared pointer to an array of T in current standard.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what you are suggesting me

Comment: `new shared_ptr<ModelType>[m_MAX]` is a pointer to a `shared_ptr<ModelType>`, but `std::shared_ptr<ModelType>` isn't. `auto p = new shared_ptr<ModelType>[m_MAX]`would most certainly work. What good it could possibly do is another matter. (See `std::vector`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have array types for shared pointers like `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` in C++11 and C++14 standards, so you can't allocate a smart pointer to an array. What you can do is construct one from a unique pointer to an array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class ModelType{
};
int main(){
    const int M_MAX = 123;
    std::unique_ptr<ModelType[]> arr(new ModelType[M_MAX]);
    std::shared_ptr<ModelType> ptr(std::move(arr));
}
```

In C++17 standard however it is possible to use a shared pointer to an array type as explained in the [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) documentation so you are able to have the:

```
std::shared_ptr<ModelType[]> arr(new ModelType[M_MAX]);
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c04d0bf02a81611e).
Prefer [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) or in your case the [boost::make_shared](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.html) to direct use of `new`.